# Is there a way to find people who liked or retweeted a tweet

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to find a way to see who liked or retweeted a tweet on Twitter, I don't wanna use these APIs as they have a limitation of the last 100.

[Twitter API retweet](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweets-id)
[Twitter API like](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/likes/api-reference/get-tweets-id-liking_users)

Is there any other way or trick to get more? (I don't wanna violate the rules)

For example, getting 10000 users who liked a certain tweet.

Comment: No, and trying to do so is a violation of their ToS. You'll have to use the API.

Comment: @pigeonburger I don't wanna violate any rule, I'm only trying to find a different route in API or any other LEGAL way, and you can't say there is no way.

Comment: Yes I can. By not using the API, you are AUTOMATICALLY violating their terms of service (feel free to read up on that). The only proper way to access Twitter data programatically is through their API. Even through web scraping (which may or may not be legal in your country), there are still rate limits that prevent you from retrieving 10000 users. What you're asking to do is impossible regardless of whether Twitter allows it or not.